# ngrx - passing in payload of triggering action to next action

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm new to ngrx and Angular development. I have a collection of trades in my store. An effect listens to LoadTradeRequest which fires an http request to get Observable and triggers a LoadTradeSuccess or LoadTradeFailure.

```
@Effect()
loadTrade$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(ActionTypes.LoadTradeRequest),
mergeMap((action: actions.LoadTradeRequest) =>
  this.remoteApiService.loadTrade(action.payload).pipe(
    map(trade => new actions.LoadTradeSuccess(trade)),
    catchError(err => of(new actions.LoadTradeFailure(err)))
  )
 )
);
```

A reducer function for LoadTradeSuccess action adds the loaded Trade to the store.

```
  case ActionTypes.LoadTradeSuccess: {
  return { ...state, trades: [...state.trades, action.payload] };
}
```

My State declaration is

```
trades: Trade[];
```

All works fine so far. I now need to change the State to a make the trades collection keyed on a unique identifier which is given in the action payload of LoadTradeRequestAction

Desired State

```
trades: DictionaryItem<string, Trade>[];
```

where DictionaryItem is

```
export interface DictionaryItem<K, V> { 0: K; 1: V; }
```

How do I pass in a property of the action which triggered the effect to the action which it triggers along with the http response. The block below doesn't work and just tries to illustrate what I want to achieve.

```
@Effect()
loadTrade$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(ActionTypes.LoadTradeRequest),
mergeMap((action: actions.LoadTradeRequest) =>
this.remoteApiService.loadTrade(action.payload).pipe(
map(trade => new actions.LoadTradeSuccess({**action.payload.UniqueIdentifier**, trade})),
catchError(err => of(new actions.LoadTradeFailure(err)))
 )
)
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, 
Can you please attach the error you are getting?

Comment: @rahul you’re trying to pass 2 parameters to action constructor. Type the payload as object with 2 properties and pass matching object. Also any reason not to use the latest version of ngrx? (just follow the docs)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want, but you do have visibility over `action` in the "what  you want to achieve example", so you could retrieve the key from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of you action must receive two params:

```
class LoadTradeSuccess {
  constructor(readonly id: any, readonly  trade: any){}
}
```

Or a payload object, but then you have to create the object in the effect

```
class LoadTradeSuccess {
  constructor(readonly payload: any){}
}


map(trade => new actions.LoadTradeSuccess({id: action.payload.UniqueIdentifier, trade: trade })),
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not creating the object of DictionaryItem<K, V> { 0: K; 1: V; } correctly. I had to use {id: action.payload.UniqueIdentifier, trade: trade } and not { action.payload.UniqueIdentifier, trade } which I had.